# Error When Adding XML Files to Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, r.java-file

Okay, sorry for asking this question. I have no idea how to solve this problem. I am creating a new project in eclipse, put some XML files in res/layout folder, and then drag an drop existing java files to src folder. I tried to generate R.java by cleaning the project and then these error messages appear:

```
[2014-02-10 18:28:01 - EventPlanner] W/ResourceType( 7228): ResXMLTree_node size 0xffffffff or headerSize 0xffff is not on an integer boundary.
[2014-02-10 18:28:01 - EventPlanner] E:\Andika\workspaces\EventPlanner\res\layout\activities_list.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/activity_id').
[2014-02-10 18:28:01 - EventPlanner] E:\Andika\workspaces\EventPlanner\res\layout\activities_list.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/chk_box').
[2014-02-10 18:28:01 - EventPlanner] E:\Andika\workspaces\EventPlanner\res\layout\activities_list.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/res_text').
.....
```

And R.java file wasn't generated. I have tried to close the eclipse and then re open again but it doesn't solve my problem. Did I miss something? Thank you

Edit: this is one of my XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/black" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:paddingTop="10.0dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_login_form" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person" />
            <EditText android:textColor="@color/black" android:id="@id/username" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Username" android:ems="20" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:paddingTop="5.0dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_login_form" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_action_secure" />
            <EditText android:textColor="@color/black" android:id="@id/password" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Password" android:ems="20" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:inputType="textPassword">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:textColor="@color/BlueDefault" android:id="@id/TextView01" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Login as" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:paddingTop="5.0dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Spinner android:entries="@array/account_type" android:id="@id/spinner1" android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_login_form" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:paddingTop="5.0dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:prompt="@string/manager" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button android:id="@id/cancel" android:background="@drawable/button_clicked" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_weight="0.5" style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
        <Button android:id="@id/signin" android:background="@drawable/button_clicked" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Sign in" android:layout_weight="0.5" style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:textColor="@color/BlueDefault" android:id="@id/signup" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Don't have any account? click here to sign up" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout.xml file code ?

Comment: one you try to clean the project and enable In project-->build automatic....and even clean the project..

Comment: @MehulRanpara edited

vinayManeti I've tried to clean the project and 'Build Automatically' is checked but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where ever you getting the error in xml file.

1) Just delete that whole id and rename it again with new id name.

2) I can see you are also getting errors while setting styles and background resources.
   just delete and define it again in your xml file and clean your project.

I hope this resolves your problem.....

Comment: You're right, cleaning the project doesn't help me. Although I don't know what does trigger the errors but I will use this approach for now.

Comment: Usually resource ids are not corrupted, you can drag and drop or copy paste xml file from one project to another. Rarely this things happen... But glad my answer helping you somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="10.0dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_login_form" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ems="20"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_login_form"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_secure" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ems="20"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
    android:text="Login as"
    android:textColor="@color/BlueDefault" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_login_form"
        android:entries="@array/account_type"
        android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
        android:prompt="@string/manager" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="5.0dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clicked"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clicked"
        android:text="Sign in" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/signup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
    android:text="Don&apos;t have any account? click here to sign up"
    android:textColor="@color/BlueDefault" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can't even set this layout in my project because my R.java is missing

Comment: try to remove that layout and clean your project and then put this xml file in layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

`W/ResourceType( 3640): ResXMLTree_node size 0x6f72646e or headerSize 0x6100 is not on an integer boundary.` was shown to me because I had an ampersand in the URL within strings.xml

The solution is to replace the `&` by `%26`